# Jquery UI Dialog submits but loses form variables from Perl script

Tags: jquery, forms, perl, jquery-ui

I believe I'm doing something wrong here.  I have a Perl script that says "if not submit button name submit/save, display html page.  Then on submit, run subroutines which pretty much insert6/update data to the db.

```
if ($cgi->param("group_submit") eq '') {
    &display_add_promo();
    exit(0);
} else {
    &group_product($group_id);
    my $group_page = "./group?group_id=$group_id";
            print $cgi->redirect($group_page);
            &close_and_exit;
  }
exit(0);
```

Now using JQuery I check if a "product from the new promotion code assigned is contained within the old promotion code assigned and if so through an alert.

```
\$('#dialog').dialog({
            height: 270,
            width: 500,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                    'Continue': function(event) {
                            \$(event.target).css({opacity: 0.25}).unbind();
                            \$('#my_form').unbind('submit').submit();
                            \$(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'Cancel': function(event) {
                            \$(event.target).css({opacity: 0.25}).unbind();
                            \$(this).dialog('close');
                    }
            }
});

\$('#my_form').submit(function(e) {

            \$.each(\$('#new_products').val().split(''), function(i, char) {
                    var existing = \$('#existing_products').val();

                    if (existing.indexOf(char) != -1)
                            e.preventDefault();
                            \$('#dialog').dialog('open');
            });

            return true;
});
```

Now when the dialog comes up and I hit "Continue" the script posts, but to the same page so says mozilla web console and none of my Perl logic runs and it basically seems like the page just refreshes.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried return false or event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: e to event actually fixed the issue.  Thanks you much!